# How to get the Body from a request, using httptools?

Tags: python, httpserver, uvloop

How to get request body with `content-type: Application/json` using python [httptools](https://github.com/MagicStack/httptools)?
I`m using it with uvloop.

The request class looks like this:

```
class HttpRequest:
    __slots__ = ('_protocol', '_url', '_headers', '_version')

    def __init__(self, protocol, url, headers, version):
        self._protocol = protocol
        self._url = url
        self._headers = headers
        self._version = version
```

Comment: Are you talking about [httptools](https://github.com/MagicStack/httptools)? In that case, look at `on_body`. What have you tried?

Comment: Solved! yes, thank you @MatsLindh, i add on_body method in my HttpProtocol implementation like this:

def on_body(self, body):
    self._body = body

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a method named `on_body` that will receive the body of the HTTP request as its parameter.

The supported callback functions on the object you provide when creating a `HttpRequestParser` with [httptools](https://github.com/MagicStack/httptools) are:

```
- on_message_begin()
- on_header(name: bytes, value: bytes)
- on_headers_complete()
- on_body(body: bytes)
- on_message_complete()
- on_chunk_header()
- on_chunk_complete()
```